# how to get data from axios to module.exports

Tags: node.js, axios, module.exports

I try get data from axios

example data.js

```
const axi = require('axios');
axi.get('www.datatest')
.then((rs)=>{ var data = rs.data;   });
.catch((err)=>{ console.log(err);   });
module.exports = data;
```

**Request file data.js**

main.js

```
const data = require('./data.js');
console.log(data);
```

i try run node main.js data is empty.
i'm not sure i'm was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't export dynamic data. Export a function that returns those data like this:

```
const axi = require('axios');
async function getData() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axi.get('www.datatest');
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getData
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Is it not enough a short example in my answer?

Comment: Yes i want see after get data from module please.

Comment: i want to get data to calculate after get  module

Comment: i try to  run main.js 
const reqdata = require('./data.js') 
console.log(reqdata)
show message function getData it's not show data  in function

Comment: after that do `await reqdata.getData()` in some other function